# New 'Category' Hook or Action?

Tags: categories, add-on-development, plugin, hook

When adding/deleting/editing a category in the CP, 
I would like to send that data to Mailchimp (where I ultimately will have the same categories)

How can this be achieved? Using a Action or a Hook? And how? 
I'm reading up on making Plugins, Hooks,... but I'm not sure wich Hook I can use and where to place it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no hook that runs after creating new categories, which is a shame. (You can find a [list of available extension hooks here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/index.html).)

You could try writing an extension that uses the [sessions_end hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/session/index.html#sessions-end), then checks for the various `$_GET` variables that indicate that you just created a new category, but that wouldn't account for times when someone submits the "new category" form and receives errors, nor for when someone creates a new category via the links found on the Publish Form (which are created via AJAX).

So your only alternative I believe is to [write a module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/modules.html) which does this directly by polling the database (looking at `exp_categories`) and comparing it to your MailChimp categories, then making changes as required. You would configure this using an "action" (which allows you to trigger your method with a URL like `http://mysite.com/?ACT=10`), and setup a cron job on your server to run this acton periodically.

Hope that helps.